# open an installed windows or mac application from flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

**I actually want to open installed AutoCad desktop application on the click of a button present in my flutter web application.**

*I searched for this on internet but couldn't find any answer.*

**1.** Is there any way to open installed application on windows or mac from a flutter web on click of a button?

**2.** Is there any package available?

**3.** Do I need to right any native code?

Answer (score 1):

Get the path of the software like.. `C:\Program Files\Autocad\...` then use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#file-scheme-handling) to open the file on the click of the button.. but as per the documentation states, you should check if the file exists or not before opening it

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: @BilalSaeed-FlutterDeveloper can you post snippets of your code, so that we can help?

Comment: [Click to see the snippet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xl-IdE0Jpp-tIcS5kjqPEa3V5gSqYbAv/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: @BilalSaeed-FlutterDeveloper you are using a windows OS.. so the path is not correct.. you are using a forward slash.. while you should be using two backslashes.. it should be `C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\bin\\netbeans64.exe` you should use two backslashes to indicate its a path

Comment: const url = 'C:\\Program Files\\CCleaner\\CCleaner64.exe'; _launchURLnew(url);
      
      void _launchURLnew(String url) async {
      await launchUrl(Uri.file(url), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);

just opens the folowing url

    http://192.168.1.5:8080/C%3A%5CProgram%20Files%5CCCleaner%5CCCleaner64.exe